# What are some open source web portal applications in C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are some open source web portal applications, preferably written in C# and ASP.NET, that are suitable for internal use in IT organisations?

Comment: What are your actual needs for the CMS software?  Will you have to extend it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/), it's an opensource ASP.NET/C# CMS

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DotNet Nuke Community Edition](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/). It is open source on Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is an open source ASP.NET/C# CMS.